# Best way of creating ad and ad-free version of an Android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ads

I have been wondering what is the best way of creating an ad and ad-free Android app. What I found are product flavors, but they require making different packages, more code and etc. I need something very simple, since the only thing that is being changed is a simple View in the layout. 
 Even If gradle's product flavors are used I can't figure out a way of changing the View, because I can only have 1 Manifest file with flavors but 2 types of Activities must be used(1. with the adView 2. without the adView).
So, what are my options here? Can these flavors bu used with different manifest files and activities?

Comment: You can remove adds with IAP, just load another layout without adView when a purchase has been made, or remove adView mannualy.

Comment: I was thinking about making 2 separate apps in the Google Play Store.

Comment: On a second thought, IAP is a better solution. Thanks, I will use that. :)

Comment: Ok, you're welcome :)

Comment: You are absolutely right, mate. Cheers :)